# Table names classifications starting with and ending with in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-like

Let me explain with simple examples , basically we have some complex design of table naming conventions at least in stage schema there are 4 patterns.

Total LAYERS 4

1. STAGE LAYER
2. BASIC DATA STORE LAYER
3. EDW LAYER
4. MART LAYER

**All the below pattern specifically fall in STAGE Layer only**

**STAGE LAYER** - 'DS_00','DSC_00','DSP_00','DT'

In this schema when looking for search pattern combination i need to consider the tables beginning with 'DS_00','DSC_00','DSP_00','DT' (the below explained patterns) and Ending with (T,W,W01,W02,W03,W1,W2,W3),so the table must be classified as STANADARD_NAMING_CONV else NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV

T - Technical
W - Working Tables

**Pattern 1**

DS_00_to_99 (00_to_99 - is the number to identify which system the table is being loaded from source)
DS_SYSTEM_NO_TABLENAME_ENDING
SYSTEM_NO - 00_to_99
TABLENAME - full table name
ENDING - not all cases the table is clssified as (T,W,W01,W02,W03,W1,W2,W3)
so the numbers range as mentioned 00 to 99 is also same for other patterns 1 as well.

**Pattern 2**

DSC_00_to_99 (00_to_99 - is the number to identify which system the table is being loaded from source)
DSC_SYSTEM_NO_TABLENAME_ENDING
so the numbers range as mentioned 00 to 99 is also same for other patterns 2 as well.

**Pattern 3**

DSP_00_to_99 (00_to_99 - is the number to identify which system the table is being loaded from source)
DS_SYSTEM_NO_TABLENAME_ENDING
so the numbers range as mentioned 00 to 99 is also same for other patterns 3 as well.

**Pattern 4**

DT_ABC_FHSJ
DS_TABLENAME_ENDING
so the numbers range is not applicable for this pattern

**BASIC DATA STORE LAYER** - 'DS'

In this schema when looking for search pattern combination i need to consider the tables beginning with 'DB' and Ending with (D,F,L,T,W,W01,W02,W03,W1,W2,W3) ,so the table must be classified as STANADARD_NAMING_CONV else NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV

**EDW LAYER** - 'DE'

In this schema when looking for search pattern combination i need to consider the tables beginning with 'DB' and Ending with (D,F,L,T,W,W01,W02,W03,W1,W2,W3) ,so the table must be classified as STANADARD_NAMING_CONV else NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV and in this layer there are some other tables which begin with TBD_ must be classified as TO_BE_DROPPED and TMP_ must be classified as TEMPORARY_TABLE

**MART LAYER** - 'DM'

In this schema when looking for search pattern combination i need to consider the tables beginning with 'DB' and Ending with (D,F,L,T,W,W01,W02,W03,W1,W2,W3,A,AD,AM,AQ,AY) ,so the table must be classified as STANADARD_NAMING_CONV else NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV and in this layer there are some other tables which begin with TBD_ must be classified as TO_BE_DROPPED and TMP_ must be classified as TEMPORARY_TABLE

`D` - Dimension tables
`F` - Fact tables
`L` - Lookup tables
`T` - Technical tables
`W` - Work tables
`A` - Aggregate Fact Tables
`AD` - Aggregate Fact Daily
`AM` - Aggregate Fact Monthly
`AQ` - Aggregate Fact Quarterly
`AY` - Aggregate Fact Yearly

**Query 1 - OLD Query**

```
SELECT owner,
         object_name,
         beginning,
         ending,
         --count(*),
         CASE
         WHEN ( beginning, ending ) IN (
                ( 'DS', 'T' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W01' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W02' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W03' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W1' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W2' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W3' ),
                ( 'DB', 'D' ),
                ( 'DB', 'F' ),
                ( 'DB', 'L' ),
                ( 'DB', 'T' ),
                ( 'DB', 'W' ),
                ( 'DB', 'W01' ),
                ( 'DB', 'W02' ),
                ( 'DB', 'W03' ),
                ( 'DB', 'W1' ),
                ( 'DB', 'W2' ),
                ( 'DB', 'W3' ),
                ( 'DE', 'D' ),
                ( 'DE', 'F' ),
                ( 'DE', 'L' ),
                ( 'DE', 'T' ),
                ( 'DE', 'W' ),
                ( 'DE', 'W01' ),
                ( 'DE', 'W02' ),
                ( 'DE', 'W03' ),
                ( 'DE', 'W1' ),
                ( 'DE', 'W2' ),
                ( 'DE', 'W3' ),
                ( 'DA', 'D' ),
                ( 'DA', 'F' ),
                ( 'DA', 'L' ),
                ( 'DA', 'T' ),
                ( 'DA', 'W' ),
                ( 'DA', 'W01' ),
                ( 'DA', 'W02' ),
                ( 'DA', 'W03' ),
                ( 'DA', 'W1' ),
                ( 'DA', 'W2' ),
                ( 'DA', 'W3' ),
                ( 'DA', 'A' ),
                ( 'DA', 'AD' ),
                ( 'DA', 'AM' ),
                ( 'DA', 'AQ' ),
                ( 'DA', 'AY' )
              )
         THEN 'STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION'
         WHEN object_name LIKE 'TBD%'
         THEN 'TO_BE_DROPPED'
         WHEN object_name LIKE 'TMP%'
         THEN 'TEMPORARY_TABLE'
         ELSE 'NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION'
         END AS table_classification
  FROM   (
    SELECT owner,       
           object_name,
           CASE first_separator
           WHEN 0
           THEN NULL
           ELSE SUBSTR( object_name, 1, first_separator - 1 )
           END AS beginning,
           CASE last_separator
           WHEN 0
           THEN NULL
           ELSE SUBSTR( object_name, last_separator + 1 )
           END AS ending
    FROM   (
      SELECT owner,       
             object_name,
             INSTR( object_name, '_', 1 )  AS first_separator,
             INSTR( object_name, '_', -1 ) AS last_separator
      FROM   dba_objects
    WHERE  owner in ('DI_STAGE','DI_BDS','DI_EDW','DI_MART')   
      and    object_type='TABLE'
      group by owner,object_name
      order by owner desc 
    )
  );
```

**Query 2 - Final Query - Worked**

```
SELECT OWNER, 
       OBJECT_NAME, 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME, '^([A-Z0-9$]{1,})_([A-Z0-9$]{1,})_.*','\1_\2')AS  BEGINNING, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(OBJECT_NAME, '[^_]*$') AS ENDING, 
      CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^D(S[CP]?|T)_.+_(T|(W0?[123]?))$')
       THEN 
         'STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION' 
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^DB_.+_(D|F|T|W|W1|W2|W3)$')
           THEN 
         'STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION' 
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^DE_.+_(D|F|L|T|W|W01|W02|W03|W1|W2|W3)$')
      THEN 
         'STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION'
         WHEN OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'TBD%' 
        THEN 
            'TO_BE_DROPPED' 
         WHEN OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'TMP%' 
        THEN 'TEMPORARY_TABLE' 
         WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^DM_.+_(D|F|L|T|W|W01|W02|W03|W1|W2|W3|A|AD|AM|AQ|AY)$') 
       THEN 
         'STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION' 
         ELSE 'NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION' 
       END 
       AS TABLE_CLASSIFICATION 
FROM   DBA_OBJECTS 
WHERE  OWNER IN ('DI_STAGE', 'DI_BDS', 'DI_EDW', 'DI_MART') 
       AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' 
GROUP  BY OWNER, 
          OBJECT_NAME 
ORDER  BY OWNER DESC, 
          OBJECT_NAME;
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS - Matched**

```
SNO OWNER  OBJECT_NAME       BEGINNING ENDING  TABLE_CLASSIFICATION 
01  DI_BDS DB_PROD_DGGAA_D   DB_PROD   D       STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
02  DI_BDS DB_CUST_DHHA_F    DB_CUST   F       STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
03  DI_BDS DB_DHSHJA_HHSGS_T DB_DHSHJA T       STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
04  DI_BDS DB_DHS_DHHA_W     DB_DHS    W       STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
05  DI_BDS DB_GSG_DHHA_W01   DB_GSG    W01     STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
06  DI_BDS DB_GFS_FHSH_W02   DB_GFS    W02     STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
07  DI_BDS DB_FGS_FHS_W03    DB_FGS    W03     STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
08  DI_BDS DB_DJJ_GSA_W1     DB_DJJ    W1      STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
09  DI_BDS DB_DKS_SJ_W2      DB_DKS    W2      STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
10  DI_BDS DB_DJA_DT_W3      DB_DJA    W3      STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION
11  DI_BDS DB_DHH_DG         DB_DHH    DG      NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV
12  DI_BDS DB_DNS_DRS_123    DB_DNS    123     NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV
13  DI_BDS DB_FHD_DRS_1      DB_FHD    1       NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV
14  DI_BDS DB_OKS_DRS_0      DB_OKS    0       NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV
15  DI_BDS DB_SKG_DRS_90     DB_SKG    90      NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONV
```

Finally worked

Comment: How do you define standard and non-standard names?

Comment: @GMB updated the questions in details now please have a look

Comment: `case when regex_like(table_name,'^DB_.+_[DFTW]$')` will match any name starting with `DB_` and ending with `D`, `F`, `T` or `W`.
You can define alternatives with `(ABC|DEF|GHI)` meaning any of `ABC`, `DEF` or `GHI`.
You can combine and nest these, e.g. `'^DE_.+_([FT]|W0?[123])$'`. (`?` means zero or one occurrence, `+` means one or more.) And so on. I suggest researching regex syntax.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks for the alternatives , i have tried but i was not able to incorporate the logic in my code , can you please update the query ?

Comment: By the way, the rule that all tables belonging to `DWH_STAGE_LAYER` must be prefixed `DS_` etc seems a little pointless to me. The mandatory `DWH_` prefix and `_LAYER` suffix for all schema names doesn't seem to add much value either. Couldn't they just have been `STAGE`, `EDW` and `DATAMART`? Or, since all tables are prefixed anyway, just have one schema, simplifying code, support and deployments? I sometimes wonder whether designers of multi-schema schemas really understand schemas.

Comment: Also, your examples don't include the schema name. `DE_PROD_RECORD_D` is shown as 'standard' but it would be nonstandard if it belonged to `DWH_STAGE_LAYER`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - Many thanks for the logic ,  i have now corrected my question with explanation , please see the section **Corrected and Updated Description with Examples and Expected Result**

Comment: It seems the requirement and the corresponding lists of examples grow ever longer. The key variables are schema, prefix and suffix. Is it possible to summarise those rules in less than 450 lines?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - I have reconstructed the question with expected results ad also i have tried to use a NEW QUERY , can you suggest

Comment: It's not a good idea to format text as code, because it just becomes one long line which is harder to read. The actual schema names seem to be part of the logic, but it is still not clear what they are or which one goes with each of the 4 patterns. We don't know what a 'Layer' is. I still think my answer solves the issue in principle, though it might need one or two extra conditions or a tweaked regex.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson- i have updated a note , the 4 patterns goes in stage schema only

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - I am also near by to my solution , but i am missing how to exclude the table ending with numbers 0-9 , i have filtered one schema just to reduce the display for easy understanding,  can you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is a pattern matching issue, but the patterns are also conditional on the table owner. I make it something like this:

```
with test (owner, table_name) as
     ( select 'DWH_STAGE_LAYER',    'DS_WHATEVER' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_STAGE_LAYER',    'DS_ANYTHING_F' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_CONS_REV_F' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_CONS_REV_F34' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_ORDER_ENTRY_W' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_ORDER_ENTRY_W12' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_PROC_SALE_A' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_PROC_SALE_A12' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_PROC_SALE_AD' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_PROC_SALE_AD11' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_PROC_SALE_AM' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_PROC_SALE_AQ' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_PROC_SALE_AQ234' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER', 'DM_WHATEVER_AQ' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_EDW_LAYER',      'DM_WHATEVER_AQ' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_EDW_LAYER',      'DE_EMP_POOL_T' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_EDW_LAYER',      'DE_EMP_POOL_T33' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_EDW_LAYER',      'DE_PROD_RECORD_D' from dual union all
       select 'DWH_EDW_LAYER',      'DE_PROD_RECORD_D123' from dual
     )
select t.owner, t.table_name
     , case
           when t.owner = 'DWH_STAGE_LAYER' and t.table_name like 'DS\_%' escape '\' then 'Y'
           when t.owner = 'DWH_EDW_LAYER' and regexp_like(t.table_name,'^DE_.+_[DFLTW]$') then 'Y'
           when t.owner = 'DWH_DATAMART_LAYER' and regexp_like(t.table_name,'^DM_.+_([DFLTW]|A[DMQY]?)$') then 'Y'
           else 'N'
       end as valid
from   test t
order by t.owner, t.table_name
```

| OWNER | TABLE_NAME | VALID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_CONS_REV_F | Y |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_CONS_REV_F34 | N |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_ORDER_ENTRY_W | Y |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_ORDER_ENTRY_W12 | N |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_PROC_SALE_A | Y |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_PROC_SALE_A12 | N |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_PROC_SALE_AD | Y |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_PROC_SALE_AD11 | N |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_PROC_SALE_AM | Y |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_PROC_SALE_AQ | Y |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_PROC_SALE_AQ234 | N |
| DWH_DATAMART_LAYER | DM_WHATEVER_AQ | Y |
| DWH_EDW_LAYER | DE_EMP_POOL_T | Y |
| DWH_EDW_LAYER | DE_EMP_POOL_T33 | N |
| DWH_EDW_LAYER | DE_PROD_RECORD_D | Y |
| DWH_EDW_LAYER | DE_PROD_RECORD_D123 | N |
| DWH_EDW_LAYER | DM_WHATEVER_AQ | N |
| DWH_STAGE_LAYER | DS_ANYTHING_F | Y |
| DWH_STAGE_LAYER | DS_WHATEVER | Y |

**Note** following comments:

I still don't understand your business rules, but the regex for *'Begins with DS and ends with any of T, W, W01, W02, W03, W1, W2 or W3'* can be written as

```
^DS_.+_(T|W|W01|W02|W03|W1|W2|W3)$
```

which could be condensed to

```
DS_.+_(T|(W0?[123]?))$
```

If the prefix can be not just `DS` but also `DSC` or `DSP` with the same suffix rule, that would be

```
^DS[CP]?_.+_(T|(W0?[123]?))$
```

If we want to add `DT` to the list, I make that:

```
^D(S[CP]?|T)_.+_(T|(W0?[123]?))$
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to parse out the prefix and suffix into separate columns and use `in` lists to check them, I would group them together using something like:

```
case
    when begins_with in ('DS', 'DSC', 'DSP', 'DT') and ends_with in ('T', 'W', 'W01', 'W02', 'W03', 'W1', 'W2' or 'W3') then 'Y'
    when begins_with in ('X', 'Y', 'Z') and ends with in ('BLAH1', 'BLAH2', 'BLAH3') then 'Y'
    when ...
    else 'N'
end as valid
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want something like:

```sql
SELECT owner,
       object_name,
       beginning,
       ending,
       CASE
       WHEN ( beginning, ending ) IN (
              ( 'DS', 'INS' ),
              ( 'DE', 'D' ),
              ( 'DE', 'T' ),
              ( 'DM', 'F' ),
              ( 'DM', 'W' ),
              ( 'DM', 'A' ),
              ( 'DM', 'AD' ),
              ( 'DM', 'AM' ),
              ( 'DM', 'AQ' ),
              ( 'DM', 'AY' )
            )
       THEN 'STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION'
       WHEN object_name LIKE 'TBD%'
       THEN 'TO_BE_DROPPED'
       ELSE 'NON_STANDARD_NAMING_CONVENTION'
       END AS table_classification
FROM   (
  SELECT owner,       
         object_name,
         CASE first_separator
         WHEN 0
         THEN NULL
         ELSE SUBSTR( object_name, 1, first_separator - 1 )
         END AS beginning,
         CASE last_separator
         WHEN 0
         THEN NULL
         ELSE SUBSTR( object_name, last_separator + 1 )
         END AS ending
  FROM   (
    SELECT owner,       
           object_name,
           INSTR( object_name, '_', 1 )  AS first_separator,
           INSTR( object_name, '_', -1 ) AS last_separator
    FROM   dba_objects
    WHERE  owner in ('DWH_STAGE_LAYER','DWH_EDW_LAYER','DWH_DATAMART_LAYER')  
    AND    object_type='TABLE'
  )
);
```

Comment: @rakesh Updated to remove the extra comma from the `IN` list.

Comment: Add another `WHEN` condition to the `CASE` statement.

Comment: Just match `DS` and then the ending. Also, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Little things like adding another condition to a `CASE` statement are things that you ought to be able to try to solve; if you have problems then you can ask a new question rather than continually creeping the requirements of the existing question but you need to make sure that when you ask you use a [MRE].

Comment: I have updated the query and also desired result , can you please suggest ?

Comment: My code already matches the `DS`/`INS` pair. I you want to match more then just add extra conditions to the `CASE` statement.

Comment: no what i am saying is i have table beginning with DS_00_CUST_INS - in these cases the ending must not be considered and result should show as STANDARD_TABLE , but  ( 'DS', 'T' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W01' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W02' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W03' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W1' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W2' ),
                ( 'DS', 'W3' ), for these combinations only the data is showing as standard ,so the tables which doesn't start with DS_00 to DS_99 (range) we must also consider as STANDARD_TABLES (valid tables)

Comment: Many thanks for driving through the logic ,finally it worked for me